# How to save a pdf file on Amazon elastic beanstalk server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am deploying a web app on amazon elastic bean server, and I am using the free version. I would like to save the PDF file on the server after parsing a JSON response in spring framework. How can I save the pdf file on amazon elastic bean? I do not want to keep it in DB.

Answer (score 1):

To store files I suggest using a S3 bucket. Use the amazon SDK to do it. For java, see [com.amazonaws.services.s3 putObject Interface AmazonS3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Refer these nice article https://medium.com/oril/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-bucket-using-spring-boot-483fcb6f8646

https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-java

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use [Spring Content](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content).  Then you don't need to worry about how to implement any of this code yourself and you have much more flexibility over where to store your images now and in future.

It is pretty easy to an existing Spring MVC application:

> pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/pdfs");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> PdfStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="pdfs")
  public interface PdfStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

That's it.  Now you will have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based pdf service at `/pdfs` that will use your PdfStore to store (and retrieve) PDFs stored on your elastic bean server at `/path/to/your/pdfs`.

So...

`curl --upload-file example-pdf.pdf /pdfs/example-pdf.pdf`

will upload example-pdf.pdf and store it in `/path/to/your/pdf/example-pdf.pdf` on your server then:

`GET /pdfs/example-pdf.pdf`

will return download it.

If you want to store the images in an S3 bucket instead then all you need to do is change the first dependency to spring-content-s3 and update the `@Configuration` to `@EnableS3Stores` and add connection details for an S3 bucket.  Reference guides are at the bottom of [this page](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).

HTH

Comment: I didnt understand how your solution works?   @StoreRestResource(path="pdfs")
  public interface PdfStore extends Store<String> {
  }  just some xyz path n code will take care of storing it on s3 bucket?

Comment: Basically yes.  What happens is that you declare a dependency on `spring-content-fs` (for the filesystem, or `spring-content-s3` for s3 if you prefer) and create the `PdfStore` interface.  When your application starts Spring Content will look at that dependency and the interface and inject an implementation of the interface for the filesystem (or s3) so you don't need to write it.  It will also look at the `spring-content-rest` dependency and inject an `@Controller` implementation (REST API) that talks to the interface as well so you don't have to write that either.

Comment: lmk if you would like me to refactor the answer for spring boot or s3 and I can do so.

Answer (score 0):

i think it may helps, below code you can use for download file.

```
@RequestMapping(value="download", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void downloadPDFResource( HttpServletRequest request,
                                     HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //If user is not authorized - he should be thrown out from here itself

        //Authorized user will download the file
        String dataDirectory = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/PDF/");
        Path file = Paths.get(dataDirectory, "file.pdf");
        if (Files.exists(file))
        {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=downloadedfile.pdf");
            try
            {
                Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```